# Can AS3 handle HTTP errors with Payloads?

Tags: actionscript-3, http

I'd like to implement a RESTful API which returns HTTP error codes when needed. Can ActionScript 3 handle an HTTP error code (404, 500) response which contains a JSON message in its payload?

Are there any good references that I can use as feedback for our in-house Flash front-end team?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access AS3 URLLoader return data on IOErrorEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188887/how-to-access-as3-urlloader-return-data-on-ioerrorevent)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this too. It seems that the answer is "no", AS3 cannot.

I have, intermittently,  seen data come in through IOErrorEvent.currentTarget.data, but I am not able to consistently reproduce this.

Answer (score -1):

You probably can do URLRequest and then handle the HTTP status

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("XMLFile.xml");
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);

private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
      trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
}

loader.load(request);
```

check the complete example :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html

you can add dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); to find out whats coming back.

Comment: If the server has sent back 404 with a JSON payload, will loader.load(request) still receive the payload?  Or does AS3 short circuit the response returning only the 404 status?

Comment: -1 I've tested this solution and it doesn't seem to work. The "complete" event never gets hit after the "ioError" event happens.